# Link to create a new email in Outlook 365

Tags: office-365, outlook-365

How do I make a link that will open a new email page in Outlook Office 365?
For example, http://webmail.cris.com.tz/?view=compose&to=doublea@test.com
will open a new email page in Zimbra webmail if we've already logged in to the webmail.

I'm wondering whether I can make a link like this so that anyone in the organization can click a link to open a new email page with a recipient email included in Outlook Office 365.

Comment: Won't a `mailto:` link work?